# Bluemix Single Sign On - remove self registration

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I've just integrated my app with IBM's SSO via Cloud Directory. The idea here is that I want access to be very secure and only authorized users (pre-approved) can access the application (e.g. website in this case).

However, I've just realised now that anyone that goes to the app's webpage can, instead of logging in, just select "Register New User" and fill in some details and he's given access? Is there a way to:

1) EITHER keep that registration form, but require one of the admins to approve it before access is given? (better solution)

2) OR completely remove the self-registration option?

As the current situation is far from secure for what I need.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I couldn't find it either. As a temporary solution, I deleted the registration link and html pages, but this definetely does not suffice for a production environment. We might just ditch the Cloud Directory and hook up Active Directory

Answer (score 1):

I talked with the support team and that is the best (only) way to do it, just remove the links from the HTML templates.